# Using classes from a jar library gives me a strange JNI error

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javac

This only happens when I'm using a jar file. I have a `MouseTest.java` file and a `MazeRunnerAssets.jar` file in the same directory. I also have `.java` files in another directory I'm compiling. This is my command using javac:

```
javac -cp MazeRunnerAssets.jar Maze_DS/MouseTest.java ../src/Maze_DS/*.java
```

when I do `java Maze_DS.MouseTest` I get:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: actor/Actor
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: actor.Actor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

If I remove the code inside of `MouseTest.java` that is using certain classes inside MazeRunnerAssets.jar then it will run. Both `java` and `javac` have the same version. What could be the problem?

My directory structure is:

```
MazeRunner/
├── src/
│   ├── Maze_DS/
│       ├── other .java files...
├── test/
    ├── Maze_DS/
        ├── MouseTest.java
    ├── MazeRunnerAssets.jar
```

The directory I'm running the command from is `MazeRunner/test`.

It says it can't find `Actor`, which is one of the classes inside the .jar file.

Inside the .jar file there are a list of directories that contain `.class` files, .png files, a manifest file, etc.:

```
MazeRunnerAssests.jar:
actor/
-------- Actor.class
asset/
grid/
gui/
META-INF/
world/
```

Comment: can you provide the structure of the jar with at least the actor package and Actor class as an example

Comment: In addition to above is actor.Actor class visible? How do you compile the MazeRunnerAssets? Are you using java 9 with module system, if so how the module info files are declared, etc...?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere Yes, it's there.

Comment: @itwasntme The actor class is visible. I don't know what that other stuff means. All I did was run the command above and I'm getting this error. The .jar file was provided to me and all of the files have `package Maze_DS` at the top of them

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove the jar from your directory when running the command?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere If I run the command without the jar file I get a bunch of errors.

Comment: You gave a bit of file structure of jar file, what about more details of it? Are there any module or package info java files inside it?

Comment: @itwasntme There's just a bunch of `.class` and `.gif` files in each directory. There's a `manifest` file that says :`"Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.7
 Created-By: 1.8.0_192-b12 (Oracle Corporation)
"`

Comment: If your code references class(es) in a jar, you need to **supply that jar** on the classpath (or on newer versions possibly the modulepath) both at compiletime and **also at runtime**. There are many ways of doing so, but since you used `javac -cp MazeRunnerAssets.jar` the simplest is to also use `java -cp MazeRunnerAssets.jar`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks but now it says "cannot find or load main class Maze_DS.MouseTest". `MouseTest.java` definitely has a public main().

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you actually need `java -cp MazeRunnerAssets.jar:.` (i.e. also specify the current directory) (on Windows change : to ; )